# How to run or access linux system directory by Java

Tags: java, linux

I try to use java to build a Snort GUI in CentOS 7, and there is a problem that linux not allow java program access system directory.Is there any way to make java access system library?

Some of the commandSender.class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class commandSender {
public static String snortLocal="/usr/sbin/";
public static String rulesLocal="/etc/snort/rules/local.rules";
public static String logLocal="/var/log/snort/";
public static String ethDevice="enp0s25";
public static String configLocal="/etc/snort/snort.conf";

public static void makeComm(int option) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    if(option==1){
        String local=getSnortLocal();
        String comm=checkSnort();
        Controller.exec(sendComm(local, comm));
    }
    else if(option==2){
        String local=getSnortLocal();
        String comm=startSnort();
        Controller.exec(sendComm(local, comm));
    }
    else if(option==3){
        SettingGUI.setting();
        String local=getSnortLocal();
        String comm=startSnortNIDS();
        Controller.exec(sendComm(local, comm));
    }
    else if(option==4){
        //kill 

    }
    else if(option==5){
        String local=getSnortLocal();
        String comm=showVersion();
        Controller.exec(sendComm(local, comm));
    }

}

public static String getLogLocal() {
    return logLocal;
}

public static void setLogLocal(String logLocal) {
    commandSender.logLocal = logLocal;
}

public static String[] sendComm(String local, String comm){
    String[] commmand={local, comm};
    return commmand;
}   

public static String checkSnort(){
    configLocal=getConfigLocal();
    String checkSnort="snort -T -c "+rulesLocal;
    return checkSnort;
}

public static String startSnort(){
    configLocal=getConfigLocal();
    ethDevice=getEthDevice();
    String startRules="snort -dv -i "+ethDevice + " -l "+logLocal;
    return startRules;
}

public static String startSnortNIDS(){
    configLocal=getConfigLocal();
    ethDevice=getEthDevice();
    String startRules="snort -dv -i "+ethDevice+" -c "+configLocal+" -A fast -l "+logLocal;
    return startRules;
}
```

The controller.class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Controller {

public static Process exec(String[] command) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    p.waitFor();
    is.close();
    reader.close();
    p.destroy();
    return null;
}
```

The Error Message:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/sbin/": error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
at Controller.exec(Controller.java:7)
at commandSender.makeComm(commandSender.java:21)
at GUI$3.mouseClicked(GUI.java:172)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 37 more
```

I already set java, javac, javaws and the jar right to become 777

Comment: Does the linux user running your java program have access to `/usr/sbin`?

Comment: Also, you're apparently trying to execute `/usr/sbin/`. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Changing the permissions of `java`, the JAR etc. has no effect on what you want to achieve. Please change them back to the values they had before, the current values make your system insecure! For the same reason, do not blindly change permissions when you do not know what it will achieve.

Comment: I have change permissions back than, and I the whole command I out put is /usr/sbin/snort -T -c /etc/snort/rules/local.rules, but it seem cannot access /usr/sbin/ so it cannot run

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the array `{"/usr/sbin/", "snort -T -c /etc/snort/rules/local.rules"}` to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` (for the case `option==1`, similarly for the others).

This is wrong for two reasons: the first value of this array needs to designate the command to execute, not only its directory, i.e., it should be `/usr/sbin/snort`. Furthermore, each parameter needs to be its own element of the array.

Thus, in total the array should look like this: `{"/usr/sbin/snort", "-T", "-c", "/etc/snort/rules/local.rules"}`. I suggest to use an `ArrayList` for constructing the command-line by appending all the values you need, and then create an array from it with `list.toArray(new String[0]);`.

Comment: Sorry, but it become No such file or directory

Comment: Check if you have `snort` installed in the correct place, and if your array really contains the expected strings (print it before command execution). If it still does not work, ask a new question.

Comment: snort is install at right place and the command print out is right, most likely is java cannot access the linux library. Anyway thx for your help.

Comment: No, this is very probably not the case. Are you sure you have each part of the command in its separate string, and not all in one string? Please create a new question with your current code and the exact content of the array you are executing.

Comment: Thanks man, I finally find the problem, I type a space in every value, much thanks